# Spring 4.2.2 CORS Support not working

Tags: spring

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
}
```

I'm following the guide in https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework and added the above code to my WebConfig

However, CORS is not working, log show

```
20151103 183823 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (DispatcherServlet.java:1136) - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my/url] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I can successfully call my api without CORS(same domain), so it is not the api problem.

In Chrome console, log show

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/my/url. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.       
Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Comment: Any additional info? Possible, it is not related to the CORS. Do you try to remove this?

Comment: I'm able to handle the options request myself previously using Filter. In the guide link above, it said a HandlerMappings will be registered when I override the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but it does not in my case

Comment: In the line from log there are no info about Spring's CORS itself. Possible, there is a mistake in other conf of the app. Can you post it all here? But it is a warning, not error. What exactly does not work in app after launch?

Comment: I can successfully call the request without CORS,

Answer (score 3):

Just add this filter for CROS in package which is contain other configuation

```
@Component
    public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        }

        public void destroy() {
        }

    }
```

It will work fine for you.

Comment: previously I'm using one like this, it work for normal CORS request, but I faced one problem when my spring security redirect the request, and the CORS request fail with 302 status code

Comment: As I remember to have read somewhere, CORS specification doesn't support redirects.

Comment: So I have no way to access api with redirect?